# Can my Dialogflow parameter be a dictionary

Tags: dialogflow-cx

What is the most efficient way to wrap a large number of parameters into a dictionary or JSON object to pass outside of Dialogflow CX

Currently, my script captures a large number of variables as parameters

```
p1 = 'Joe'

p2 = 'DiMaggio'

p3 = 'New York Yankees'

p4 = 'MVP'
```

My script will ultimately need to pass on these values as a dictionary {'first_name':p1, 'surname':p2, 'team':p3, 'award':p4} in an API call

I would like to define my parameter as dictionary "player" and then define as required
player.first_name,  player.surname, player.team, and player.award

However, Dialogflow seems to regard those 4 variables as unrelated string names.

Answer (score 0):

You can send them as a dictionary or a JSON object as long as you stick to the expected format of the fulfillment response.

This is how I tried it out to work:

Sample parameters:

```
const sampleParams = {
  "player": {             
      "firstName": "Virat",
      "lastName": "Kohli",
      "team": "India",
      "award": "MVP - ICC World Cup 2023"
   }
};
```

Webhook response body:

```
const result = {
  fulfillmentResponse: {
    messages: [
      {
        text: {
          text: ['Response from the webhook'],
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  sessionInfo: {
    parameters: {
      updatedParameter: sampleParams,
    },
  },
};
```

When I send this as the webhook response to the detectIntent API call, this is what gets sent back to Dialogflow:

```
{
"responseId": "904710bf-fd97-56t0-83b7-a0bd6a31698b",
"queryResult": {
    "text": "Hi",
    "languageCode": "en",
    "parameters": {
        "updatedParameter": {
            "player": {
                "team": "India",
                "firstName": "Virat",
                "award": "MVP - ICC World Cup 2023",
                "lastName": "Kohli"
            }
        }
    },
    "responseMessages": [
        {
            "text": {
                "text": [
                    "Response from the webhook"
                ]
            },
            "responseType": "HANDLER_PROMPT"
        }
    ],
... rest of the response ...
```

[image: detectIntent API response]

These parameters will remain accessible till the session expires and in the format you expected.

[Dialogflow Webhook](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/reference/rest/v3beta1/WebhookRequest). This may help.